# Trying to find a quote of the Cheshek Shlomo

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, jewish-books, technology, meat-and-milk

I'm trying to find the source of a quote I saw. I was reading [an article about test tube beef](http://www.jta.org/2013/08/07/news-opinion/world/has-the-era-of-the-kosher-cheeseburger-arrived) and came across the following:

> [Rabbi Menachem] Genack noted another source for viewing cultured meat as parve: A 19th century Vilna-born scholar known as the Heshek Shlomo, wrote that the meat of an animal conjured up in a magical incantation could be considered parve. It may not be too much of a stretch, then, to apply the same logic to modern genetic wizardry.

Some more googling led me to [a fuller citation](https://ohr.edu/5518#_edn5):

> Cheshek Shlomo (end Y”D 98, s.v. v’da).

and eventually a mention by Shlomo Stencil who called it a "manuscript on the shulchan aruch"

> [מכתב יד על שו"ע](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%91%D7%A8:%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%A6%D7%9C_(%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A5)/%D7%A7%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A1)

The Heshek Shlomo is [Rabbi Shlomo HaKohen (1828–1905)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_HaKohen_(Vilna)). He wrote a talmud commentary called Heshek Shlomo, and also a [few](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/1865) [volumes](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/1700) of shut. (He was also an editor for the Vilna Shas). I can't find a work of his that is a commentary on the Shulchan aruch. He is quoted by the Mateh Yehonatan in the Vilna SA, but I can't find the content referenced above in Siman 98.

Does anyone know where this book is? Was it given a different name? Was his commentary included in another compendium? Is there a second Heshek Shlomo? Does anyone know where this book/source is?

Comment: It may be worth checking his Talmud commentary on the story of making a cow with sefer yetzira (if he commented on it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Chesek Shlomo](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4711)(which is Rabbi Shlomo Hakohen) can be found in the back of the Shulchan Aruch (Melachim) (Kovetz Mefarshim) which has many meforshim on each siman.

Here is the text you are looking for:

[image]